# How to extract an unknown number of lines from a file and generate a new file for each?

Tags: bash

I have a text file (file_1), which will contain an unknown number of lines. I want to extract each line and place it in a new file (except the first line). I have been trying to do this using a for loop, wc, and head\tail, but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Commands I have been using:

```
wc -l File_1 > File_1.wc 
for i in $(seq 1 $(cat File_1.wc)); do head -${i} File_1 | tail -1 > File_1.${i}.txt ; done
```

Whenever I use this, I get the following error message:

```
seq: invalid floating point argument: ‘File_1’
Try 'seq --help' for more information.
```

Example File_1

```
    Aug 1, 2020  7:08 PM Start clustering of 102 queries
    GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g48.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g32.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g33.t1 GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g11.t1 GCA_001696625
    GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g10.t1 GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g11.t1 GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g12.t1 GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK000
    GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g35.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g36.t1
    GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g47.t1
    GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_4380183-4385401(+)_61
    GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_5936-11161(-)_63
```

Hypothetical output files:

File_1.1.txt

```
 GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g48.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g32.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g33.t1 GCA_001696625.1_C1HIR_9889_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g11.t1 GCA_001696625
```

File_1.2.txt

```
GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g11.t1 GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g12.t1 GCA_005930515.1_160527_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g13.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK000
```

File_1.3.txt

```
GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g35.t1 GCA_007994515.1_UK0001_genomic.fna_Candidate_Sequence_g36.t1
```

etc.

I'm not sure why this won't work. Is anyone able to suggest why and provide a new method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to program anything, there is standard Unix utility named `split` that does exactly that: splitting a file by chunks of N lines.

Here is what you are looking for, using GNU `split`:

```
$ split --lines=1 --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=5 --additional-suffix=.txt File_1 File_1.
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR>1{f="File_1." NR-1 ".txt"; print >f; close(f)}' File_1
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is coming from `seq`, which imo should not be involve in your task, since `bash` or any POSIX compliant shell has a builtin that can be used for that particular task.

Also see [Read a file or stream line-by-line or field-by-field in bash](http://%20https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Why you should not [Read lines with for in bash](http://%20https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

---

That said if the file/data is not that big (less than 1k+ lines). a while read loop can be used.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=File_1

count=1

while IFS= read -r lines; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$lines" > "$file.$((count++)).txt"
done < <(tail -n+2 "$file")
```

- `count=1` is incremented by one on every line, the `count++` inside the `$(( ))`, see [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic).
- The `>` is part of the [Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
- `IFS` see [Shell variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables)
- Run `help read` on your shell.
- Also `help printf`
- The `<( )` is called [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)
- `tail -n+2` removes the first line of the file.
- The `$(( ))` is part of the arithmetic expression/construct in bash, see [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html).